# <IPython.core.display.HTML object> instead of graph

Tags: twitter, ipython, tweepy

I am trying to achieve the following Twitter-Visualization project in iPython: http://www.amypeniston.com/web/visualizing-twitter-data

For the last step, my code is:

```
%pylab

dogs = pd.read_csv(' C:/Users/Alex/mongodb/bin/outputTweets.csv')
dogs['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(dogs['created_at']))
dogs.set_index('created_at', drop=False, inplace=True)
dogs.index = dogs.index.tz_localize('GMT').tz_convert('EST')
dogs.index = dogs.index - DateOffset(hours = 12)
dogs.index

dogs1m = dogs['created_at'].resample('1t', how='count')

v.core.initialize_notebook()
area = v.Area(dogs1m)
area.colors(brew='Spectral')
area.display()
```

However, all I get in return is:

```
IPython.core.display.HTML object
```

Comment: Are you using the notebook, or another IPython interface? What version of IPython do you have?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I use IPhython (3.4) Notebook (and QTConsole). Anaconda 3, 64bit.

Comment: 3.4 is your Python version, the current release of IPython is 3.2. If you have an older version, you can try updating it with `conda update ipython ipython-notebook` in a command prompt. HTML will only display in the notebook, not the Qt console.